# Use CSS with imgStyle in Gatsby

Tags: html, css, gatsby, gatsby-image

Is there a way to use CSS with `gatsby-image`'s `imgStyle` property?

For example, I want to be able to do something like

```
<!--In the HTML -->
<Img className="squiggle" fluid={data.squiggle.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
```

and

```
/*In the CSS */
.squiggle {
    position: absolute;
    left:-100px;
    width:465px;
    height:282px;
}
```

I don't like the syntax of having to do something like

```
<Img imgStyle={{
    position: "absolute",
    left:"-100px",
    width:"465px",
    height:"282px",
    }}
    fluid={data.squiggle.childImageSharp.fluid}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, your initial approach is perfectly valid:

However, you have to keep in mind that the use of `gatsby-image` wraps the image in a series of nested `<div>` that makes, among other things, the blur effect. So you may need to add some additional rules. In addition, `gatsby-image` uses some inline styles so they will have priority among your CSS file, you may need to use the `!important` rule to override it.

For example, a structure like you've provided will output:

```
<div class="squiggle gatsby-image-wrapper" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; width: 400px; height: 400px;"><img aria-hidden="true" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center center; opacity: 0;"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6a64a/some-image-name.webp 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/ab687/some-image-name.webp 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/88bdf/some-image-name.webp 2x"><source srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/7b2a1/some-image-name.jpg 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/d1f84/some-image-name.jpg 2x"><img srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/7b2a1/some-image-name.jpg 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/d1f84/some-image-name.jpg 2x" src="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="400" loading="lazy" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; object-position: center center; opacity: 1; transition: none 0s ease 0s;"></picture><noscript><picture><source type='image/webp' srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6a64a/some-image-name.webp 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/ab687/some-image-name.webp 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/88bdf/some-image-name.webp 2x" /><source srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/7b2a1/some-image-name.jpg 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/d1f84/some-image-name.jpg 2x" /><img loading="lazy" width="400" height="400" srcset="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg 1x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/7b2a1/some-image-name.jpg 1.5x,
/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/d1f84/some-image-name.jpg 2x" src="/static/9f5c7a959032e5fe2cba348695d4cee8/6e63d/some-image-name.jpg" alt="" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;opacity:1;width:100%;height:100%;object-fit:cover;object-position:center"/></picture></noscript></div>
```

*Note: this is an example I made for this answer. It's just an approximation, the paths may differ but the main structure don't*

As you can see, your class name is in the outer wrapper, so to maybe achieve your desired effect, you will need to point to some inner HTML tag such as `<img>`, creating a selector like: `.squiggle img{}`.